# How to get all stored Nodes in JCR?

Tags: java, jcr

we have an application that uses JCR (Jackrabbit) as its content managment system, but know we want to replace it by other (none JCR) content managment system. I want to sync my old data in JCR with this new system, so  how can I get all contents (Nodes) from JCR (Jackrabbit) to store them in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export JCR workspaces to XML through one of the [`Session.export`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html) methods.